# Restrict Client Certificate except for some pages in ASP.NET / IIS 7 or Jsp / Apache / Tomcat

Tags: ssl, asp.net, java, ssl-certificate

In IIS you can force client certificate request mais can it exclude some pages ? How is it by coding (sample code somewhere ?) or by configuration ?

Same question for Apache / Java

Answer (score 0):

For Apache, the question is easily answered: use the directive SSLVerifyClient in a Directory context. See [the mod_ssl documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient) for more info.